# How to use CKEditor 5 RTL in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm currently using Laravel 8. I want to use CKEditor 5 in Farsi language and right to left direction. I configure CKEditor like below:

```html
var allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('.html');
for (var i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {
    ClassicEditor
    .create(allEditors[i], {
        language: 'fa',
        contentsLangDirection: 'rtl',
        contentsLanguage:'fa',
        dialog_buttonsOrder: 'rtl',
    })
    .then(editor => {
        console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.stack);
    });
}
```

So my editor is compiling and the language is currect. But the direction is left to right !!! How can I fix the toolbar and content direction?

[image]

Comment: Hey bro, did you solve this? Coz I need this solution.

Comment: @Mahdi Yes I use ckeditor translation CDN file and it works. Although I missed some features but problem of rtl resolved. Check this link https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html